# Python Dictionary DataStructure which method d[] or d.get()?

Tags: python, data-structures

While Using Python Dictionary DataStructure (which contains key-value pair) if i want to retrieve some value from my Dictionary i have two options **d[''] and g.get('key')** so i am confused now which is better and Why ?? I understand both some way but when it comes to memory consumption and evaluation in memory which  one is better ??

Hoping for some Positive reply,

Regards.

Comment: g.get('key') does not throw an exception if the key is not present , g['key'] will throw exception. I am not aware of any performance bottlenecks due to any of the approaches.

Comment: @ anuj singh : i am also concern about performance bottlenecks using them alternatively but i guess reply says the it does not affect. both are same.

Comment: I hope your question is answered :), It will be really helpful if you accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From the [Python Library Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html)

> `d[key]`
>   Return the item of *d* with key *key*. Raises a `KeyError` if *key* is not in the map.
>
> If a subclass of dict defines a method `__missing__()`, if the key *key* is not present, the `d[key]` operation calls that method with the key *key* as argument. The `d[key]` operation then returns or raises whatever is returned or raised by the `__missing__(key)` call if the key is not present. No other operations or methods invoke `__missing__()`. If `__missing__()` is not defined, `KeyError` is raised. `__missing__()` must be a method; it cannot be an instance variable. [...]

and

> `get(key[, default])`
>   Return the value for *key* if *key* is in the dictionary, else *default*. If *default* is not given, it defaults to `None`, so that this method never raises a `KeyError`.

The difference lies in the return value.  When you ask for the value corresponding to a non-existing key, you either want

1. A `KeyError` raised
2. A callback invoked
3. A default value returned

Python provides the different functionalities through multiple methods.

There will be a performance hit using `[]` when the key is not found, either in calling `_missing_` or raising the exception. As to which one is faster **when the key IS present**, I checked the source code. (I used 2.7.2 for this check.)  In `dictobject.c` we see:

- `get` calls `dict_get`
- `[]` calls `dict_subscript`

Now if the values are present, in `dict_get` we have

```
if (!PyArg_UnpackTuple(args, "get", 1, 2, &key, &failobj))
    return NULL;

if (!PyString_CheckExact(key) ||
    (hash = ((PyStringObject *) key)->ob_shash) == -1) {
    hash = PyObject_Hash(key);
    if (hash == -1)
        return NULL;
}
ep = (mp->ma_lookup)(mp, key, hash);
```

and in `dict_subscript` we have

```
assert(mp->ma_table != NULL);
if (!PyString_CheckExact(key) ||
    (hash = ((PyStringObject *) key)->ob_shash) == -1) {
    hash = PyObject_Hash(key);
    if (hash == -1)
        return NULL;
ep = (mp->ma_lookup)(mp, key, hash);
```

The only difference is that `get` does an extra unpack tuple!

Significant?  I have no idea. :-)

Comment: So Ray i can say d.get() is to avoid unexpected crash and handling the values on no Key found on dict ???

Comment: @jigar The original intent of `get` was to allow for a _default_ to be returned, which makes things like counting applications very convenient.  Starting with Python 2.5, the `[]` was enhanced to avoid the exception if you configured a subclass in a certain way.

Comment: using timeit.timeit(stmt='b = a["x"]',setup='a={"x":"hello world"}', number=10000 and 100000), and then modifying the stmt to be a .get("x","") -- the time difference was 3-4x faster using the []'s vs the .get

Comment: Note that `.get()` is a method lookup and call, while `[..]` is implemented in bytecode. That makes subscription faster for the 'key is present' case, just for those reasons.

Comment: Can we use collections.defaultdict to get the same functionality as d.get(key, default_value) ?

Comment: It's not _exactly_ the same. With a `defaultdict` the factory is passed to the constructor, and every single call to `get` on it for a missing key calls the same factory method. With a regular `dict`, every single `get` call can return a different default value.

Answer (score 6):

If `'key'` does not exist in the dictionary,

`d['key']`

will throw a `KeyError`, while

`d.get('key')`

will return `None`.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that if the key is missing, `d[key]` will raise a `KeyError` exception, whereas `d.get(key)` will return `None` (and `d.get(key, default)` will return a default value).

There are no noticeable differences in memory requirements.

Answer (score 0):

They are different, especially if the key is not present in your dictionary (see [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict))

> `d[key]`
>
> Return the item of d with key key. Raises a KeyError if key is not in the map.
>
> `get(key[, default])`
>
> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else
>   default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this
>   method never raises a KeyError.

Comment: So Howard, 
i can say <b>get()</b> is to handle exception which will not effect running program and i can use default param to handle if key not found and this both using interchangeably does not affects memory at all ???

Comment: @jigar Just use the method which fits your requirements best. If you want to have an exception for missing keys use `[]` otherwise `get`. You don't have to care about running time or memory consumtion.

Answer (score 0):

They both behave the same if the key exists. But if the key is not found `d['key']` will raise a `KeyError` exception, whereas `d.get('key')` will return `None`. You can also supply a second argument to the get method which will be returned on a not-found condition: `d.get('key', '')` will return a null string if the key is not found.