# python default dictionary calling key values

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have written a bit of code using 
setting value

```
 dic["key"] = "someval"
```

and fetching it the same way

```
 print dic["key"]
```

then I discovered that an alternative way to fetch a dictionary value is to use

```
print dic.get("key")
```

I want all my code to use the same method, so should I rewrite all using dic.get("key") ?

Comment: What makes you think that `dict.get()` is the 'correct' way? That's only for when you want to retrieve the value *or a default*. For most usecases, `dic[key]` is perfectly valid!

Comment: **Note:** By default, `dic.get` will return `None`, if the `key` doesn't exist. This is something which you may not want

Comment: I would prefer it to return None so I guess that answers my question, would the performance be the same for both methods?

Comment: If you check question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631929/python-dictionary-datastructure-which-method-d-or-d-get , you'll see in the accepted answer that the difference in performance is pretty small, but there is some. I think it should not make a difference, it's more about which approach you like the most (get a None or an exception)

Comment: `.get()` requires a method call; that's an attribute lookup and a stack push. That's a little slower, but unless you are in a time-critical loop, I'd not worry about that.

Comment: My answer would be to use .get() because of the added functionality for a few cases - I would rather not mix methods for readability sake

Answer (score 1):

If you have a flat dictionary and you want to add or modify a key/value pair, than the best way is to use a simple assignment:

```
h[key] = value
```

The get method is useful when you want to get a value from a dictionary for existing keys or use a default value for non-existing keys:

```
print h.get(key, "Does not exist!")
```