# how can I stop a button from calling the write function?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I create a button on a form and a function, my problem the button calls the write function thing that i don't want because all what i want is that it changes the value of another field

```html
    @api.multi
    def write_paid(self):
        self.state_money = "paid"
```

***EDIT:***

my write method:

```html
   @api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
        Initial=self.Amount
        New=vals['Amount_entered']
        res=super(Myclass, self).write(vals)
        if vals['Amount_entered'] > 0:
            vals['Amount_date'] = fields.Datetime.now()
            vals['Amount']= Initial + vals['Amount_entered']
            res=super(MedicalLab, self).write(vals)
            record=self.browse(self.ids[0])
            self.env['journal'].create({
```

Comment: When this method called ? it's good if you can elaborate more your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Set field readonly might fix your issue.

If it's field not button then you can do something like as follow.

I think your requirement seems like that one field is depending upon another field's value.

So either you can manage `@api.onchange` method or you can manage `@api.depends`

```
@api.onchange('field1')
def onchange_field1(self):
    if self.field1 == "value"
        self.field2 = "Paid"
    ## add your logic.
```

onchange method will not trigger write method.

[Vals.get v/s vals[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631929/python-dictionary-datastructure-which-method-d-or-d-get)

Comment: it's a button not a field. All I need is that when i click a button the value of a field changes from unpaid to paid

Comment: Then it's not possible because if you will update any field's value then it must call write method.

Comment: You need to override write method and need to add your custom logic to skip process if the field gets updated.

Comment: the problem is that i already overrided it (the write method)

Comment: Add write method code or you can do one thing  set that field readonly, be default it will excluded from the vals so it won't called write method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149819/discussion-between-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd-and-sos-mona).